# How to solve Promise Pending Error in Object.length

Tags: node.js, json

I want to get my json length with `Object.key(getJsonCode).length` and `get-json library` but i have error. How i can solve this?

I'm already to tried using async and promise when i use gt-json library but not work for me

```js
const json = getJson(url).then((result) => {
    Object.keys(result).length
}).catch((err) => {
    throw err
});
```

I expect the output of my json length but the actual output is 
`Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This approach will do what you want, we use the async / await pattern:

```
async function logKeys() { 
    let json = await getJson(url);
    let keyCount = Object.keys(json).length;
    console.log("Key count: ", keyCount);
}

logKeys();
```

The issue in your example is that you are assigning a promise to the json variable. However the result of this promise will be undefined, since the first promise handler has no return value.

So that is what is printed when you do a console.log(json).

You could also try:

```
const jsonPromise = getJson(url).then((result) => {
    return Object.keys(result).length;
}).catch((err) => {
    throw err
});

jsonPromise.then(result => console.log("Key count: ", result));
```